# In perl how can I print to a file whose filehandle is resolved at the runtime?

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
my $org_file_hash = {
      'S6' => '/path/to/file/filename.txt_S6',
      'S8' => '/path/to/file/filename.txt_S8',
      'S2' => '/path/to/file/filename.txt_S2',
      'S0' => '/path/to/file/filename.txt_S0',
      'S00' => '/path/to/file/filename.txt_S00'
    };
my $filehandles;
for(keys %{$org_file_hash})
{
    my $key=$_;
    open(my $key,">",$org_file_hash->{$key}) || die "Cannot open ".$org_file_hash->{$key}." for writing: $!";
    push(@{$filehandles},$key);
}
```

In the latter part of the code, I get $org as "S2".

```
my $org="S2";
```

Based on $org I will decide the file I need to print to and in this case it is /path/to/file/filename.txt_S2.

To achieve this, I am doing following, but it does not work:

```
my $org="S2";
print {$org} "hello world\n";
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't use string ("S2") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at new_t.pl line 22.
```

Please help.

Comment: If you enable warnings with `use warnings` Perl will warn you that `$key` is re-declared. I guess that your intention was to use it's value as the filehandle name

Comment: Always, *always* use both `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. If you aren't sure what the error messages mean, also add `use diagnostics;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash:

```
my $filehandles = {};

for my $key (keys %{$org_file_hash}) {
    open my $fh, ">", $org_file_hash->{$key} or die $!;    
    $filehandles->{$key} = $fh;    
}
my $org="S2";
print {$filehandles->{$org}} "hello world\n";
```

BTW, if you use the `open my $fh, ...` form of `open`, `$fh` should be undefined. Otherwise, its value is used as the name of the real filehandle wanted. This is considered a symbolic reference, so the script won't compile under "`use strict 'refs'`".

Answer (score 3):

Use `$filehandles` as a hash (or hashref) instead of an arrayref, as such:

```
my $filehandles = {};
for my $key (keys %{$org_file_hash})
{
    # my $key=$_;     # redundant
    open( my $fh, '>', $org_file_hash->{$key} )
        or die "Cannot open ".$org_file_hash->{$key}." for writing: $!";
    $filehandles->{$key} = $fh;
}

# later...
my $org = 'S2';
print { $filehandles->{$org} } "Hello, world.\n";
```

At the end, don't forget to iterate over `keys %{$filehandles}` and `close` your `open`ed files, too.